# Removing zero before decimal point

Tags: c

How to remove zero before the decimal point?

Example:

Input:

```
0.83333
```

Output:

```
.83333
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: There's no zero in the binary data... are you asking about `printf` or some other pri9nting approach...? If so, update the question with an example code and show us what you attempted so far.

Comment: `printf` has no modifier to suppress a leading zero. You will have to edit the string yourself, which you can do by using `snprintf` to print to a buffer and then modifying it.

Comment: Ali Shan, If the value was -120.345 or -0.0000001, what output woudl you expect?

Comment: If the value was 0, what output is expected?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a first approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
...
double somenumber = 0.1234;
...
char temp[30];
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "%f", somenumber);
if (temp[0] == '0')
  memmove(temp, temp + 1, strlen(temp + 1) + 1);
...
```

Maybe you need to deal with the value 0.

Comment: BTW, the `snprintf` returns the number of characters printed/copied, so I think you could have removed `strlen` and use the return value of `snprintf`.

Comment: @AmmarFaizi sure, bit I didn't want it to overcomplicate, the OP is a beginner.